# Split text string in a data.table columns by location

Tags: r, split, data.table, strsplit

I am trying to figure it out how I can use `tstrisplit()` function from `data.table` to `split` a text by **location number**. I am aware of the [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154556/split-text-string-in-a-data-table-columns), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200179/dynamically-assign-number-of-splits-in-data-table-tstrsplit/36163991) & [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898833/splitting-text-column-into-ragged-multiple-new-columns-in-a-data-table-in-r) but these do not address my question.

as an example :

```
 DT2 <- data.table(a = paste0(LETTERS[1:5],seq(10,15)), b = runif(6))
 DT2
     a         b  
1: A10 0.4153622
2: B11 0.1567381
3: C12 0.5361883
4: D13 0.5920144
5: E14 0.3376648
6: A15 0.5503773

I tried the following which did not work:

DT2[, c("L", "D") := tstrsplit(a, "")][]
DT2[, c("L", "D") := tstrsplit(a, "[A-Z]")][]
DT2[, c("L", "D") := tstrsplit(a, "[0-9]{1}")][]
```

**The expectation:**

```
     a         b    L   D
1: A10 0.4153622    A   10
2: B11 0.1567381    B   11
3: C12 0.5361883    C   12
4: D13 0.5920144    D   13
5: E14 0.3376648    E   14
6: A15 0.5503773    A   15
```

any help with explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `tstrsplit` can't you do with `c(substr(a, 1, 1), substr(a, 2, 3))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on regex `"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])"` if you want to split between letters and digits, *(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])* restricts the split to a position that is preceded by a letter and followed by a digit:

The regex contains two parts, look behind `(?<=[A-Za-z])` which means after a letter and look ahead `(?=[0-9])`, i.e before a digit, see more about *regex* [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), in r, you need to specify `perl=TRUE` to use Perl-compatible regexps to make these work:

```
DT2[, c("L", "D") := tstrsplit(a, "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)][]

#     a          b L  D
#1: A10 0.01487372 A 10
#2: B11 0.95035709 B 11
#3: C12 0.49230300 C 12
#4: D13 0.67183871 D 13
#5: E14 0.40076579 E 14
#6: A15 0.27871477 A 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Would you please let me know why you assigned to `?` or in another words what dose `(?<=[A-Za-z])` means ? I know regex but I do not know why you assign to `?`. Furthermore, what dose `perl = TRUE` mean here as it dose not explained/defined in package?

Comment: When `?` is the first character in a regex group, it signals there will be extra options for the group.  In this case, "(?<=[A-Za-z])` means "preceded by `[A-Za-z]`, but don't include this group in the match."  Similarly, `(?=[0-9])` means "followed by a digit, but don't include this group in the match."